# All anchor tags work except top

Tags: anchor, nav, smooth-scrolling

On this [site](http://mtthwbsh.com/data-viz) I'm using a smooth-scroll function, which works on every link unless you try and go back home. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id "Home" refers to an fixed positioned element (the header), it's always visible so the script has no where to scroll to.

Swap Id's between `<header id="home">` and `<section id="intro">` to `<header id="intro">` and `<section id="home">` ,or you can just change your first list's item anchor to `<a href="#home">`that way the script has somewhere to head to.

Remove your section's padding, and apply it to a more inner element of your sections, otherwise your first section's headings will be misplaced.

Good Luck Developer!